# Update Error after 14.04 -> 16.04 upgrade(?)

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, updates

I'm in the process to upgrade (using the automatic system procedures) from 14.04 to 16.04.
Several problems are encountered: Although the new version installation  has been finished there is no GUI login yet. In addition the

`sudo apt-get update` command, ends with the error

```
appstreamcli: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libupstream.so.3: undefined symbol: _ZNK6google8protobuf11MessageLite25InitializationErrorStringB5cxx11Ev
```

Any suggestion  on how to proceed?

Comment: The undefined symbol mentioned in the question appears to be a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mir/+bug/1527137       Please report this.